# Input Validation MIPS

Tags: validation, mips, user-input

How do I validate a user input in MIPS instruction set using MARS? In my following program I want to know how I can add validation to user input for example when asking the user if they want to decrypt or encrypt a message they need to input either 'E' or 'D' (case sensitive due to ascii values). As well as an input from (1-9) which is the encryption or decryption key. If they enter anything other than 'E', 'D' and a number from 1-9 how do I ask the user to enter a valid input using a subroutine for each prompt?

Code:

```
.data
    encrypt_decrypt: .asciiz "Type(E)ncrypt/(D)ecrypt:"
    key: .asciiz "\nEnter encryption key (1-9): "
    message_prompt: .asciiz "\nEnter message: "
    output: .asciiz ""
    re_enter: .asciiz "\nWrong input"
    buffer: .space 50
.text

main: 
    # Prints the prompt asking the user if they want to encrypt or decrypt
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, encrypt_decrypt # Loads address from the user prompt
    syscall

    # Takes in E OR D based on user choice
    li $v0, 12      
    syscall
    add $t6, $v0, $0    
    bne $t6, 69, ELSE # Branch to else if inputed value is not E

    # Prints the prompt asking the user for a message to either decrypt or 
    encrypt based on the users previous choice
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message_prompt # Loads address from the users message
    syscall

    # Takes the users message
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, buffer
    lb $t0, 0($a0)
    li $a1, 48
    syscall
    la $s2, buffer

    # Asks the user for a key from 1-9
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, key
    syscall


    # Takes the users key value from 1-9
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    add $s0, $v0, $0    

    la $t0, ($s0)   # Loads key
    li $t1, 0       # Lower order bit to be toggled
    la $t2, ($s2)   # Load user message


    beq $t6, 69, encrypt # 69 Is the printable ASCII value of "E"
    beq $t6, 68, decrypt # 68 is the printable ASCII value of "D"
ELSE:
    bne $t6, 68, E_D_VALIDATION # Branch to E_D_VALIDATION if user input is not D

E_D_VALIDATION:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, re_enter
    syscall
    j main  

encrypt: 

encrypt_loop: 

    lb   $t3, 0($t2)        # Loads character bytes
    beq  $t3, 10, encrypted # Branches to "encrypted" if we reach the end of a character
    add  $t3, $t3, $t0
    addi $t4, $0, 1       
    sllv   $t4, $t4, $t1    
    xor   $t3, $t3, $t4     # Lower order bit toggle

    sb   $t3, 0($t2)        # Stored encrypted character
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    j encrypt_loop      # Loops through the list of encrypted characters
    
 encrypted:     
    li $v0, 4               # Print out encrypted message
    la $a0, output
    syscall
    la $a0, ($s2)
    syscall
    
    j exit              # Exits the program


decrypt: 
decrypted_loop:
    lb $t3, 0($t2)         # Loads character bytes
    beq $t3, 10, decrypted # Branches to "decrypted" if we reach the end of a character
    addi $t4, $0, 1
    sllv $t4, $t4, $t1
    xor $t3, $t3, $t4
    sub $t3, $t3, $t0
    sb $t3, 0($t2)        # Stored decrypted character
    addi $t2, $t2, 1

    j decrypted_loop      # Loops through the list of decrypted characters


decrypted: 
    li $v0, 4            # Print out decrypted message
    la $a0, output
    syscall
    la $a0, ($s2)
    syscall

    j exit              # Exit the program


    exit:
```

Comment: It's no different in MIPS than in C or C#.  Of course we can write conditionals in assembly.  But, what are you really asking or stuck on?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yeah, so for example in Java what I am familiar with you can simply use a scanner and use hasNextInt to check if an input is an integer or using isDigit(). In MIPS is there something similar where I can just directly compare the input to a string or integer. Or do I have to do some sort of conversion for example convert the input to ASCII or hex?

Comment: MIPS refers to an instruction set, it can even run Java.  Your question is more relevant to an execution environment, like MARS or QtSPIM: these do not have facilities to tell you if some input string (or any string for that matter) is a number vs. other.  They can request numeric input from the console, but they cannot convert a simple string as number in memory (or from a file) into that number.  So, you if you want to input as string or character, you're on your own for identification, validation, and conversion.  It is an embarrassingly incomplete programming model, but that's the idea..

Comment: I've, created a program on MARS. I should have specified in the question I will edit it and add my MIPS code from MARS. I'm trying to validate user input to be either 'E' or a 'D' and also a number from (1-9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're missing is the error handling:

```
    beq $t6, 69, encrypt # 69 Is the printable ASCII value of "E"
    beq $t6, 68, decrypt # 68 is the printable ASCII value of "D"

    <handle error here>
     
encrypt:
```

What to do to handle the error: print a message and quit, or print a message and goto someplace earlier in the code, maybe `main` or some other new label you introduce for this.

---

However, it might be nice to check for incorrect input before getting this far, and if you do that you won't have to check so much later: you can check for just E or just D instead of for both, because at this point you know it is only one or the other and nothing else.

So pseudo code you want to put immediately after inputting what should be the E or D:

```
if ( input != E && input != D ) { print input error message; goto reEnter; }
```

Where `reEnter` could be main or another location you choose to go back to get the input.

I would translate this into assembly language using the following series of transformations.

First, if-goto-label style, which skips the if-statement's then part when the condition is false:

```
    if ( ! ( input != E && input != D ) ) goto inputOk;
    print input error message
    goto reEnter;
inputOk:
    ; continue with rest of program knowing good input (exactly E or D)
```

Next: distribute the negation per [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
    if ( ! ( input != E ) || ! ( input != D ) ) goto inputOk;
    print input error message
    goto reEnter;
inputOk:
    ; continue with rest of program knowing good input (exactly E or D)
```

Next: negate the relational operators:

```
    if ( input == E || input == D ) goto inputOk;
    print input error message
    goto reEnter;
inputOk:
    ; continue with rest of program knowing good input (exactly E or D)
```

Next: split the disjunction (`||`)

```
    if ( input == E ) goto inputOk;
    if ( input == D ) goto inputOk;
    print input error message
    goto reEnter;
inputOk:
    ; continue with rest of program knowing good input (exactly E or D)
```

Now, that's pretty easy to write in assembly.

Comment: In my program I have added some stuff. `bne $t6, 69, ELSE # Branch to else if inputed value is not E` after the second syscall which asks the user to enter 'E' or 'D'. This takes me to subroutine `ELSE` if the user did not enter 'E'. `ELSE` checks if the user entered 'D' instead with the following: `bne $t6, 68, E_D_VALIDATION # Branch to E_D_VALIDATION if user input is not E or D`. As you can see if the user did not enter 'D' either then I branch to subroutine `E_D_VALIDATION` this will tell the user to enter a correct input then jump back to main to ask for the input once again.

Comment: When I enter 'D' and I branch to `ELSE`. It fails the `bne` statement inside `ELSE` and branches to `E_D_VALIDATION`, this is not what I want. It should just continue asking for a message to decrypt (since i entered 'D') and also asking for a key. Any Idea to what I did wrong here? Also when I enter 'E' the program works fine and encrypts as intended. From my code it's only when I enter 'D' that it does not work even though I believe it should. I don't know where I went wrong there.

Comment: Try to follow my logic & guidance, reread my answer.  You can see that you should be using the`==` operator not `!=`, and testing two twice, not just once.

Comment: Ok, I got it done. I was just making it more complicated than it needed to be.